# Service Checking Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a linuxserver and a linux service.
Sometime this service suddenly stop and production processes stop.
Unfortunately this situation is not welcomed or desired by anyone.
I writed a script for check this service.
This script send mail when service shutdown but this script can not automating start my service.
I dont understand why ?
What should I do for this script to start automatically when my service stops?

```
SUBJECT="Service Alarm"
TOEMAIL=myemail
pid1=`ps aux | grep service  | awk '{print $2}'`

if [ -z "$pid1" ] #Job Checking
then
echo "Service is Not Running."
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TOEMAIL" < "Service is not running"
        nohup  systemctl start service > /opt/service/logs/service_web.err.log 2>&1 &
        sleep 30
        pid2=`ps aux | grep service  | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo $pid2
if [ ! -z "$pid2" ] #Job Checking
then
echo "Service is running."
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT1" "$TOEMAIL" < "Service running"
fi
else 
echo "Service is running."
fi
```

Comment: Copy/paste your code to http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, then update your question if you still have issues you need help with.

Comment: I solved my problem with the shellcheck.net you sent.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem true and working script as follows.

> ```
> SUBJECT="Service Alarm"
> TOEMAIL=myemail
> pid1=$(pgrep -f service)
>
> if [ -z "$pid1" ] #Job Checking
> then
> echo "Service is Not Running."
> /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TOEMAIL" < "Service is not running"
>         nohup  systemctl start service > /opt/service/logs/service_web.err.log 2>&1 &
>         sleep 30
>         pid2=$(pgrep -f service)
>     echo $pid2
> if [ -n "$pid2" ] #Job Checking
> then
> echo "Service is running."
> /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT1" "$TOEMAIL" < "Service running"
> fi
> else 
> echo "Service is running."
> fi
> ```